# How to avoid python to add unwanted column to similar dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I add a new "NaN" column ("C") to a dataframe (say df) to fill it later it will be added to other similar dataframes (here: sto) which is not my case. So how should I avoid this and remain the other dataframes unchanged?

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[3,4,9]})
display(df)
```

[image]

```
sto=df
df.loc[:,"C"]=np.nan
display(df)
```

[image]

```
display(sto)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sto` and `df` are different variables pointing to the same object.
You should `sto=df.copy()` to alter `sto` without changing `df`.

You can see that `sto is df` returns True when using sto=df but False when using df.copy()

Comment: Does this happen when using "=" in other objects such as lists, dictionaries, np.arrays and we should use ".copy()" or other similar methods for them or it is just relating to pandas dataframes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference and try by yourself